# c# how to modify parameter that is passing through a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, pass-by-reference

I have the following delegate

```
System.Action<SomeMessage> TheDelegate;
```

Which has a couple subscribers, however as the message gets passed through all the subscribers, each subscriber will do something to it and that change persists and gets passed to the next subscriber, which is something that I don't want.

Is there a way that I can use the original message as the parameter for all subscribers?

Edit:
SomeMessage is a class, thus it gets passed by reference through the subscribers

Comment: What is `SomeMessage`? Is it a struct?

Comment: It is a class, so the parameter gets passed as a reference

Comment: Since the class is passed by reference, you only need one single original message. I think this is already the required behaviour you described.

Comment: Sorry that my expression is really bad. So I want to use the original message yet I don't want any changes caused by the subscribers to persist.

Answer (score 0):

To name two possibilities:

- Clone the message each time it is passed to a subscriber. How is the message structured, is it cheap to clone? Maybe you could even pass it as `struct`? Cloning could be done by implementing `ICloneable`, clone on a per-property basis, which can be automated by a framework, e.g, Automapper (http://automapper.org) or, if you mess around with some JSON Lib like JSON.NET, you could do something like `var clone = FromJson(ToJson(original))`. This is surely not a fast approach but an easy one that works well with deep objects.
- Another way would be making the message itself immutable and let each subscriber pass change requests to some kind of collector, e.g.

like this:

```
interface ICommandSequence
{
    void AddCommand(ICommand);
}
```

and the Action becomes

```
System.Action<ImmutableMessage, ICommandSequence>
```

Each subscriber could now pass command instances to the `ICommandSequence` instance. And after all subscribers have been called, you could execute the command sequence, and apply changes to message objects. How the commands look depends on the way your messages and message processing looks.

If your application cares about a design that is strongly focused on the business domain, you could build commands that represent real-world business events, as it is done in CQRS, for example.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first possibility a little bit? I was thinking about that but couldn't find a way to do so. If I do something like `TheDelegate(message.Clone())`, the same thing would happen as the changes to the clone persists as well.

Comment: OK how does your message object look? Is it flat? Are the properties primitive types? Anything fancy that would make cloning hard? You have to clone the message each time for every subscriber, then the changes are surely isolated.

Comment: I added some information about clone implementation